# What changes needed to support IPv6

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ipv6, ipv4

What changes website needed to support IPv6 and IPv4?
Also using socket service in java what changes i require to accept both type of connection ?

**Environment**

OS - Linux

Webserver - Tomcat 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OS supports IPv6 and is configured correctly then you do not need to do anything on the Java/Tomcat side.

Comment: @sohilv: That's a different question.  You can look at https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/installation-guide/amd64/linux-upgrade.html for IP6 configuration information.